# Prove this geometrical statement

Tags: geometry

Let ${p}$ and ${q}$ be the radii of two circles passing through ${A}$,touching ${BC}$ at ${B}$ and ${C}$, respectively. Then prove that ${p.q=R^2}$ where ${R}$ is the circumradius of ${ABC}$.

Thank you! :)

Edited: @newbie : This is the construction according to your details! 
                  Its not coming accurate!
[image: Gelometric construction according to @newbie]

The question represents the following figure.
[image: Original Question]
One has to prove that ${\LARGE{p.q=R^2}}$.

My Thoughts: I am thinking of the following logic(2nd diagram):

${{\LARGE{cos}}(\angle{ABE})=\frac{\frac{c}{2}}{p}}$     ...(1)

${{\LARGE{cos}}(\angle{ACG})=\frac{\frac{b}{2}}{q}}$     ...(2)

And from Extended Law of Sines we get,

${{\LARGE{sin}}(\angle{ACB})=\frac{c}{2R}}$       ...(3)

${{\LARGE{sin}}(\angle{ABC})=\frac{b}{2R}}$       ...(4)

Now using these four equations, I have to prove the result! This is where I'm stuck and need help.

Comment: What is $R$ here ?

Comment: Radius of circumcircle of triangle ${ABC}$. :)

Comment: What did you try to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: I tried applying extended sine rule but it did not help much. I also tried by creating external triangles ${ABC'}$ and ${AB'C}$ where ${C'}$ and ${B'}$ are centre of the external circles. :)

Comment: You should consider those two circles are tangent to each other, otherwise I doubt you would reach a unique solution. "Touching $BC$" also means two circles are tangent to line $BC$.

Comment: @newbie:But, then it will be solution for only one special case when the circles are tangent to ${BC}$. But, in generality,it is not necessary that the circles are tangent to ${BC}$, since a circle can pass through a point on a line segment even if it is not a tangent. It can be seen in the second diagram. :)

Comment: @AbirMukherjee: (1) If the circles aren't tangent to each other, then how do you decide which point of intersection is $A$? (2) If the circles aren't tangent to $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$, then you can move, say, $C$ to a new position $C^\prime$ on $\bigcirc Q$ such that $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ABC^\prime$ (which both satisfy the conditions of the problem) have different circumradii (which cannot both be given by $\sqrt{pq}$).

Comment: @Blue:May be you are right! But to prove that ${BC}$ is a tangent to the circles, I need a proper mathematical statement about why it should be a tangent. If possible, can you give a proper solution of this question assuming that ${BC}$ is a tangent. Thanks! :))

Comment: @AbirMukherjee: I believe the fact that the word "touch" is used indicates that tangency is intended. Interestingly, from my GeoGebra experiments, once $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$ is assumed tangent to the circles, it doesn't matter which point of intersection is $A$: the circumradius is the same for both possible triangles. (I don't have a proof yet, though.)

Comment: @Blue: Ok, I will try to find a proof assuming that ${BC}$ is a tangent. But, I would also request you to search for a proof since this will help the community! Thank you for your kind help! :))

Comment: Why the `\LARGE` sine and cosine?

Comment: @Rahul: I felt it would look nice when it's \LARGE. No reason behind it though! :))

Answer (score 3):

I assume here that $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$ should be *tangent* to the circles, whose centers I denote $P$ and $Q$. Let $R$ be the center of the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$, and let the circumradius be $r$.

[image]

Write $\beta$ and $\gamma$ for $\angle ABC$ and $\angle ACB$, respectively. Noting that $\angle PBC$ and $\angle QCB$ are right angles (by the tangency of $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$), we can deduce that $\angle APB = 2\beta$ and $\angle AQC = 2\gamma$. (This is actually an aspect of the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem).) Consequently, 
$$|\overline{AB}| = 2p\;\sin\beta \qquad \text{and} \qquad |\overline{AC}| = 2q\;\sin\gamma$$

By the Law of Sines, we know that 
$$2 r = \frac{|\overline{AC}|}{\sin\beta} = \frac{|\overline{AB}|}{\sin\gamma}$$
whence
$$(2 r)^2 = \frac{|\overline{AC}|}{\sin\beta} \cdot \frac{|\overline{AB}|}{\sin\gamma} = \frac{2q\;\sin\gamma}{\sin\beta} \cdot \frac{2p\;\sin\beta}{\sin\gamma} = 4 p q \qquad \to \qquad r^2 = p q$$

Note that the argument holds regardless of which point of intersection of $\bigcirc P$ and $\bigcirc Q$ is taken to be $A$.

Comment: Thank you for this solution! It's elegant! :))

Answer (score 0):

Draw lines $BE$, $CF$, $AB$, $AC$ and $EF$ ($E$ and $F$ are the centers of two circles respectively).

Furthermore, draw a line orthogonal to $AB$ intersecting $BC$ at $G$ and link $AG$. Because $\triangle BEG\cong\triangle AEG$ we know $AG\perp EF$ and $AG=BG$. Similarly we have $AG = CG$.

On the other hand, since $\angle BEA+ \angle AFC = \pi\implies \angle EAB + \angle AFC = \pi/2\implies\angle BAC = \pi/2$.
Once again we have $AG = BG = CG$, given $BG = CG$. Furthermore they are the circumradius of $ABC$.
The equality $pq = R^2$ can be obtained from the similarity of e.g. $\triangle EGA$ and $\triangle EGF$.

Comment: I tried the construction on GeoGebra. Its not coming accurate! :)